# Replace countifs with advanced filter or other macro - guidance appreciated

Tags: excel, vba, lookup, criteria

I have quite a heavy workbook.
I am curious if any of you could advise how to best do it so that the processing speed isn't affected much.

sheet `Occupancy`: 
[image: See image]

```
TblOccupancy[code]
TblOccupancy[start]
TblOccupancy[end]
TblOccupancy[setting]
```

The above is used on another sheet.

Sheet `Numbers`:
[image: See image]

`column B6:B370` contains dates
range `CODES_PASTETO` which is `c3:ie5` contains 3 criteria
row `3` = setting
row `5` = code

I have created a formula that counts number of users of given code present on specific date.

I was hoping you could help me converting this into macro [Excel-vba]

and that it would in turn speed up processing and automation in general.

This is what I use in `c6:ie370`:
`=IFERROR(IF($B6>Today,0,SUMPRODUCT((occupancy_code=Numbers!C$5)*(occupancy_startdate<=Numbers!$B6)*(occupancy_enddate="")*(occupancy_setting=Numbers!C$3))),"-")`

Thank you in advance.
At the moment testing advanced filter, struggling with multi-criteria & between dates. I will comment if i solved this one. In the meantime sending hugs for anyone willing to help!

Comment: @ashleedawg thank you for tiding up; apologies for the eye sore

Comment: The equivalent `COUNTIFS` might execute faster.

Comment: @ron rosenfield Thank you. It did speed up the process. Figured this out a few minutes ago. `=IF($B48>Today,"-,COUNTIFS(occupancy_code,Numbers!C$5,occupancy_startdate,"<="&Numbers!$B48,occupancy_enddate,"",occupancy_setting,Numbers!C$3))]`. Still working on vba solution.